How to import a shapefile into Google My Maps
I am using Google My Maps to work on a simple agriculture project. I drew polygons and lines for structures, boundaries, etc. and that works great.
Now I found some data online that I want to show that comes in a shapefile format which I am not familiar with. From searching I understand it's meant to be used with GIS software but I can't figure out how to import it into Google My Maps. Any advice?

You can't import a shapefile. But you can import a KML/KMZ file. Most GIS software can convert a shapefile to a KML or KMZ but if you don't have GIS software you can use an online converter such as mygeodata.cloud or aspose.app.
Once you have created a KML or KMZ, you can add a layer and import the KML or KMZ.




